# python array count each elements

Tags: python, counter, frequency

I want a small program to count each part numbers enter by user.
here is so far I can do.

Is there a way I can export part numbers and their frequency to .csv file?

```py
from collections import Counter
thislist = []
frequency = []
partnumber = ""
def mainmanu():
    print ("1. Create List")
    print ("2. Print list")
    print ("3. Exit")
    while True:
        try:
            selection = int (input("Enter Choice: ")
            if selection ==1:
                creatlist(thislist)
            elif selection ==2:
                counteach(thislist)
            elif selection ==3:
                break
    except ValueError:
        print ("invalid Choice. Enter 1-3")
def creatlist(thislist)
   # while True:
        partnumber = input  ("Enter Part number: ")
        if partnumber =="end":
            print(thislist)
            mainmanu()
            break
        thislist.append(partnumber)
def counteach(thislist)
    Counter(thislist)
    mainmanu()

mainmanu()
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the StackOverflow.

You are calling the mainmanu function inside another function which is called by mainmanu function. Instead what you should be doing is letting mainmanu calling all the other helper functions. Antoher thing, you can't call break in another function and expect where it is called to break.

The execution goes like this:

mainmanu is called, it calls creatlist, after it finishes execution it continues to execute the instructions where it is left from.

```
 from collections import Counter
        thislist = []
        frequency = []
        partnumber = ""
        def mainmanu():
            print ("1. Create List")
            print ("2. Print list")
            print ("3. Exit")
            while True:
                try:
                    selection = int (input("Enter Choice: ")
                    if selection ==1:
                        if creatlist(thislist): # line x
                            break
                    elif selection ==2:
                        counteach(thislist)
                    elif selection ==3:
                        break
            except ValueError:
                print ("invalid Choice. Enter 1-3")


        def creatlist(thislist)
           # while True:
                partnumber = input  ("Enter Part number: ")
                if partnumber =="end":
                    print(thislist)
                    return True #this value will make the the condition to be true see line x
                thislist.append(partnumber)
                return false


        def counteach(thislist)
            Counter(thislist)
        mainmanu()
```